# How many directive use ngModel as an Input and how many directive use it as selector?

Tags: angular

After reverse engineering the two Angular form modules (FormsModule and ReactiveFormsModule), I counted three uses of ngModel as an input in a directive.

In **FormsModule**, ngModel is used once in the **NgModel** directive. ngModel is part of the directive selector (selector: '[ngModel]:not([formControlName]):not([formControl])'). So, for the NgModel directive, ngModel has two roles. It's an input and at the same time a selector.

In ReactiveFormsModule, the ngModel is used twice. The first use is in the **FormControlDirective** (selector: '[formControl]').
The second one, is in the **FormControlName** directive (selector: '[formControlName]'). In both cases, ngModel is a simple input and it's not a part of the directive selector.

The three occurrences allow to bind a FormControl to model. But, the first one has an other side effect: it also create the FormControl before binding it to model.

Are there other uses ? Do I missed other ones ?

Comment: `ngModel` is just a selector, it's not clear what you're asking. Can you make your question more specific?

Comment: It seems like it's not just a selector (at least in one case). Here the code https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/69c53c3e03c7a8bb2260496c9aa32925cd2d59b4/packages/forms/src/directives/reactive_directives/form_control_name.ts#L90

Comment: The question can be rephrased as such: how many directive use ngModel as an Input and how many directive use it as selector ?

Comment: see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47380272/2545680)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how many directive use ngModel as an Input and how many directive use
>   it as selector ?

#### The following directives use `ngModel` as input binding:

Reactive forms:

- formControl
- formControlName

Template driven forms:

- ngModel

#### The following directives use `ngModel` as selector:

- `NgModel` template driven directive
- All built-in validators with there  respective attribute: `[required][ngModel]`, `[email][ngModel]`, `[minlength][ngModel]` etc.
- All built-in control value accessors like `DefaultValueAccessor`, `NumberValueAccessor` etc. Read here in depth about `ControlValueAccessor`: [Never again be confused when implementing ControlValueAccessor in Angular forms](https://blog.angularindepth.com/never-again-be-confused-when-implementing-controlvalueaccessor-in-angular-forms-93b9eee9ee83)
- `NgControlStatus` that is automatically applied to Angular form controls that sets CSS classes `ng-valid`, `ng-pending` and others based on control status

Answer (score 0):

[(ngModel)] is mostly used as a two-way-binding which means you can pass its value to a variable in you TS or JS file.
I´ll give you an example.

```
<input [(ngModel)]="array.test"</input>
```

Will give your JSON-array an attribute test with the value written in your input.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The question is not about what it does or how to use it. It was much about the internals of Angular.